# Cant access Json Array values created by json_decode

Tags: php, json

My json_decode() is returning an array but i just cant seem to access it. Here's as much of information i think would be useful. I'm pulling a json value from a server using curl commands.

The response (output) from the server :

```
//php code from getVal.php 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
echo($response);
var_dump($response);
```

[image]

```
{ "automat": false, "brightness": null, "increase: set time": 2, "decrease: set time": 2 } string(101) "{ "automat": false, "brightness": null, "increase: set time": 2, "decrease: set time": 2 } "
```

Converting the json formatted string to json array:

```
//php code from getVal.php 
$res = json_decode($response, true);
echo($res);
echo("<br><br>");
var_dump($res);
echo("<br><br>");
echo($res["automat"]);
```

output:
[image]

```
Array

array(4) { ["automat"]=> bool(false) ["brightness"]=> NULL ["increase: set time"]=> int(2) ["decrease: set time"]=> int(2) }
```

Clearly $res prints as Array for some reason, and when trying to print $res["automat"] it doesn’t t print anything at all. I've checked the console and there is no errors.

Solutions already tried with no result :

```
//1: 
$response =  stripslashes($response); 
//2: 
$response = html_entity_decode($response);
//3: 
$nbsp = html_entity_decode( "&nbsp;" );
$response = str_replace( $nbsp, "", $response);
//for each above 
$res = json_decode($response, true);
```

Any further information can be provided if asked.

Comment: `echo($res);` prints `Array` (try `var_dump($res);`), but `var_dump($res["automat"]);` should prints `bool(false)`.

Comment: Please, don't post code as **image**. Edit your question and paste output as text.

Comment: oka will change the op to code thgt itd be easier my bad

Comment: @JaisonThomas  please add real output of `var_dump($response);` in your code, as well as real output of `var_dump($res);`

Comment: oka i've added the real outputs aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to echo a bool with a `false` value. It will not return/print anything.

You can test this, be executing the following code:

```
echo '('. NULL .')' . "\r";
echo '('. false .')'. "\r";
echo '('. true .')' . "\r";
```

This will give your output:

```
()
()
(1)
```

In order to see something from your example, use another key for this:

```
echo $res["increase: set time"];
```

P.S. Don't use images for showing source code.

Comment: Okay u were right i tried $res["increase: set time"] it returend 2,  thanks